# Gradle, how to force to select last version of third part dependencies

Tags: gradle

I'm having some warnings regarding a dirty classpath:

```
w: Runtime JAR files in the classpath have the version 1.2, which is older than the API version 1.3. Consider using the runtime of version 1.3, or pass '-api-version 1.2' explicitly to restrict the available APIs to the runtime of version 1.2. You can also pass '-language-version 1.2' instead, which will restrict not only the APIs to the specified version, but also the language features
w: C:\Users\gbarbieri\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-reflect\1.2.50\9fab8887f91c8e17cce1a7522f45dc25976e57b9\kotlin-reflect-1.2.50.jar: Runtime JAR file has version 1.2 which is older than required for API version 1.3
w: C:\Users\gbarbieri\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-common\1.2.50\6b19a2fcc29d34878b3aab33fd5fcf70458a73df\kotlin-stdlib-common-1.2.50.jar: Runtime JAR file has version 1.2 which is older than required for API version 1.3
w: C:\Users\gbarbieri\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib\1.2.50\66d47b004c5b8a1d2d1df9e463187390ed741316\kotlin-stdlib-1.2.50.jar: Runtime JAR file has version 1.2 which is older than required for API version 1.3
```

Then, I have been trying to force to select the last version of these third part dependencies using:

```
    constraints {
        testImplementation("$kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version")
        testImplementation("$kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version")
        testImplementation("$kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version")
    }
```

This worked on some other projects, but I cant seem to get it working [here](https://gist.github.com/elect86/2c43ed496589d4f82145c19a0bc3dbe3)

If I ran

`gradle -q dependencyInsight --dependency kotlin-stdlib --configuration testCompileClasspath`

I get the [following](https://gist.github.com/elect86/05b0b94bed62eee5c8529556708a4677)

And in the Idea Gradle window I can still see some unwanted dependency, such as `kotlin-reflect:1.2.50`

Why?

Ps: project is this [one](https://github.com/kotlin-graphics/glm)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this seems working:

```
project(":glm") {
    dependencies {
        constraints {
            testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version")
            testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version")
            testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version")
        }
    }
}

project(":glm-test") {
    dependencies {
        constraints {
            implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version")
            implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version")
            implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version")
        }
    }
}
```

But if I try to parametrize the begin of the strings into `constraints` in this way:

```
buildscript {    
    ext{
        kotlin = 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin'
    }
}
```

Then it doesnt work anymore.. weird